# jQuery - Not adding class in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, safari

I've written some jQuery which works with the Image Map Hotspot plugin to add classes to the pop-up based on the icon used.

This works across Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari, I was wondering if anyone could identify why?

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.info-icon').each(function() {
    var icon = $(this);
    var bgImg = $(this).css('background-image');


    if (bgImg == 'url("http://www.domain.com/client1/wp-content/themes/BespokeTheme/images/purple-circle.svg")') {
        $(this).prev().addClass('detected-pu purple-popup');
    }
    if (bgImg == 'url("http://www.domain.com/client1/wp-content/themes/BespokeTheme/images/orange-circle.svg")') {
        $(this).prev().addClass('detected-pu orange-popup');
    }
    if (bgImg == 'url("http://www.domain.com/client1/wp-content/themes/BespokeTheme/images/green-circle.svg")') {
        $(this).prev().addClass('detected-pu green-popup');
    }
    if (bgImg == 'url("http://www.domain.com/client1/wp-content/themes/BespokeTheme/images/lblue-circle.svg")') {
        $(this).prev().addClass('detected-pu lblue-popup');
    }
    if (bgImg == 'url("http://www.domain.com/client1/wp-content/themes/BespokeTheme/images/dblue-circle.svg")') {
        $(this).prev().addClass('detected-pu dblue-popup');
    }
  })    
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(bgImg)` to see what Safari thinks it is

Comment: This kind of coding really never works well, where you're trying to match urls or colors from CSS with hardcoded values, there's just too many things that can mess that up, different browsers return different things etc.

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry to resurrect an old thread, but if you'd like to post this as an answer with a little bit more of an explanation of how this would have helped, I'll be happy to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To Jaromanda X - Not sure why I didn't think of logging the bgImg to see what Safari thought it was!

Turns out Most browsers were returning the url("http://...") string, whereas Safari was dropping the double quotes, resulting in the url being tracked as url(http://...)

All resolved now, Thanks Jaromanda for the pointer!